# Tikz fails creating an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I found that I cannot creating ellipse with Tikz 3.0.1a for the following example

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node(a) [ellipse,draw] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with error message:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ellipse' and I am going 
to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \node(a) [ellipse,draw]
```

while the following code works well

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) ellipse [x radius=20pt, y radius=10pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Do I miss something here?

Comment: If you want an ellipse-shaped node, you need to load the tikz `shapes.geometric` library. Only `circle`, `rectangle` and `coordinate`are defined initially. see section 67 p 693 of the manual

Comment: @BambOo Would you be willing to turn this into a real answer?

Comment: @marmot, will do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want an ellipse-shaped `node`, you need to load `tikz` `shapes.geometric` library. Only `circle`, `rectangle` and `coordinate` are defined initially. 
See section 67 p 693 of the [manual](http://ctan.mines-albi.fr/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Please note that though Hirak's answer provides ways to obtain ellipses, some comments can be formulated

- `\draw ... ellipse` is an ellipse-shaped `path` not a `node`
- scaling `tikzpictures` can lead to great modifications in a graphic and should be done carefully
- the `shapes` library is provided in the latest versions of `pgf-tikz` for compatibility reasons, it has been superseded by the `shapes.geometric` and `shapes.misc` libraries.

Comment: Very good and I upvote you,

Comment: Thank you. I accept your answer. I was trying to search in the manual but still could not the answer. Thank you

Comment: @zhidayat, after some time it gets easier :)

Answer (score 2):

An easy and simple way to draw an ellipse is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2.5cm and 1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Another way is to do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=2]
\draw (0,0) circle (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT :** This may possibly be closer to what you are asking.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[thin, draw=black, ellipse, minimum width=10cm,minimum height=5cm,align=center]
\node (a) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Though what you propose allows to draw ellipses with tikz, this does not answer the OP's question.